# Distinct on specific column in Hive

Tags: unique, distinct, hive

I am running Hive 071.
I have a table, with mulitple rows, with the same column value.

```
 x | y |
---------
 1 | 2 |
 1 | 3 |
 1 | 4 |
 2 | 2 |
 3 | 2 |
 3 | 1 |
```

I want to have the x column unique, and remove rows that have the same x val;

```
 x | y |
---------
 1 | 2 |
 2 | 2 |
 3 | 2 |
```

or

```
 x | y |
---------
 1 | 4 |
 2 | 2 |
 3 | 1 |
```

are both good.

As distinct works only on the whole row in Hive, I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distinct on specific column in Hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401818/distinct-on-specific-column-in-hive)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the distinct keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x FROM table
```

Comment: this is problematic, since I need to receive both X and Y but with X distinct.  In some DBs this can be done using "select distinct on x,y from tabel" but hive dosent support "distinct on"

Answer (score 2):

try following query to get result :

select A.x , A.y from (select x , y , rank()  over ( partition by x order by y)  as ranked from testingg)A where ranked=1;