# Distinct on specific column in Hive

Tags: unique, distinct, hive

I am running Hive 071 I have a table, with mulitple rows, with the same column value e.g.

| x | y |

---

| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

I want to have the x column unique, and remove rows that have the same x val e.g.

| x | y |

---

| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |

or

| x | y |

---

| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

are both good as distinct works only on the whole rs in hive, I couldn't find a way to do it

help please Tx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distinct on specific column in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401543/distinct-on-specific-column-in-hive)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some options:

**1) This will give you the max value of y for each value of x**

```
select x, max(y) from table1 group by x
```

Equally you could use avg() or min()

**2) OR, you could collect all the values of y in a list:**

```
select x, collect_set(y) from table1 group by x
```

This will give you:

```
x|y
1|2,3,4
2|2
3|1,2
```