# Add unique value in hive table

Tags: hive, apache-pig, auto-increment

I want to add a unique value to my **hive** table whenever i enter any record, that value should not be repeated in the entire hive table. I am not able to find any solutions or any function for this. In my case i want to enter the record in hive using **pig** latin. Please help.

Comment: How much control do you have over the inserts? do you know the max batch size?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz at a time i am paarsing only one file.

Comment: Any reason not to use `row_number () over ()`?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I am inserting my data to hive using pig. How can i use `row_number()` in pig script ?

Comment: Check for the DISTINCT clause.
The below link might help .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401543/distinct-on-specific-column-in-hive

Comment: @KeshavPradeepRamanath i don't want to remove any records as i need all of them. So Distinct won't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

HIVE does not provide RDBMS database like constraints.

The suggested approch using PIG Script is as below.
    1. Load data
    2. Apply DISTINCT to data
    3. Store data at a location
    4. Create external hive table at the same location.

Step 3 and 4 can be combined if you can use HCATALOG which allows you to directly store data in Hive table.

Official documentation :[Link 1](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#DISTINCT) [link 2](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/hcat-r0.5.0/loadstore.html)

Comment: can you please share the link ?

Comment: [1]: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#DISTINCT
[2]: https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/hcat-r0.5.0/loadstore.html

Comment: How does it apply to the OP request?

Comment: @GopalRajput i am not sure whether this solution will work or not.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz is there any way i can add auto increment feature in my hive table itself ? so that whenever i add record that value will get updated.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

did you take a look to this? https://github.com/manojkumarvohra/hive-hilo it seems to provide a way to generate sequence numbers in hive using hi/lo algorithm

Comment: Can you provide any examples ? It would help me in understanding it better.